# How to use PCA model on BigQuery ML for classification

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, pca, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have created a PCA model on BiqQuery but I am having a hard time figuring out how o use it for a classification problem I have. I can use ML.EVALUATE but that is about it. How do I go about using my PCA model to train for a classification model?

I tried different ML functions like predict, confusion matrix, and ROC but the last 2 don't work since I haven't been able to train a classification model using the PCA data. Below is my code

```
CREATE MODEL
  `mydataset.mymodel`
OPTIONS
  ( MODEL_TYPE='PCA',
    PCA_EXPLAINED_VARIANCE_RATIO=0.8 ) AS
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `mydataset.mytable`

SELECT * FROM
ML.EVALUATE (MODEL 'mydataset.mymodel',
( SELECT target FROM 'mydataset.mytable'))
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

after training a PCA model, you can use ML.PREDICT(MODEL `mydataset.mymodel`, data) to transform the original data into its embedded space (i.e., principal components). In this way, dimensionality reduction is achieved. You can also toggle this "keep_original_columns" argument in ML.PREDICT to pass through additional features that you don't want to transform. This is the link to "keep_original_columns": https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-predict#keep_original_columns

You can then use this transformed data to a classifier model in bqml, such as logistic regression, boosted tree classifier, random forest classifier, etc.

If you have more questions, please email bqml-feedback@google.com